# Gmail Inbox Issue

Tags: gmail

My inbox has been doing something odd that I really need to stop.  I've been looking for a job and every response I get from online submissions is showing up in both the primary and the promotions tabs. I can't figure out why it started and I can't figure out how to stop it.  I certainly don't need two tabs with the same emails. I've tried to Google the problem, I've looked all over different forums, I even tried (in vain) to contact some kind of support line but couldn't find one.  Can someone help me please?